# Problem with distance in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, distance, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I start a new project with base on OpenLayers plugin but if I check the distance on QGIS with distance tool (I choose a straight road) I view 5.466m on QGIS and 4.300m on google (by walking).

How is it possible?

On QGIS 2.6.1 I do not set any CRS

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95133/

Answer (score 3):

I am no expert in this but from my understanding:

- The OpenLayers plugin in QGIS uses the *EPSG:3857* CRS which is a *projected* CRS on a **flat surface** (here's a very good [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48949/epsg-3857-or-4326-for-googlemaps-openstreetmap-and-leaflet) describing it). Therefore, it calculates a straight-line distance as you would on a paper map.
- I can't find how Google Maps calculates its distances but a common method would be to use the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) or "as the crow flies". This calculates distances from two points on a **sphere**. There is a forum [here](http://www.quora.com/How-does-Google-Maps-calculate-the-distance-from-one-place-to-another) suggesting what Google Maps uses to calculate distances.

So in terms of calculating distances, Google Maps provides a more accurate measurement assuming your CRS is set to *EPSG:3857* in QGIS. You should always use the CRS of the local country to give you the best distance measurement.

Hope this helps and if anyone spots a mistake, please correct me :)

Comment: In my situation the difference is over 20%, I think there is an error in the project but I am not able to find it

Comment: You should never do measurements that you hope to do accurately in any sort of projected coordinate system.  It is best to use a geographic coordinate system (such as 4326) and use the Haversine formula to do any sort of mapping.  If you are concerned with having a higher accuracy over smaller distances than use a local projection system that preserves distances.

Answer (score 1):

Joseph's answer assuming it has something to do with straight-line distance is not correct.

Although the question is different, the answer is the same as [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245151/why-does-reprojection-with-gdalwarp-change-pixel-size/245156#245156) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/264954/87998).

---

The QGIS ruler calculates the distance in the viewers projection which I assume is Web Mercator (EPSG:3857) in your case.

WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator (EPSG:3857) projection is heavily distorted when moving away from the equator. Thus, it could be discussed if the units should be called "*Pseudo-meters*". One meter in reality is approximately 1/cos(lat) pseudo-meters.

```
4300 m / cos(38.1°) = 5466 pseudo-meters
```

[image]

*[CC BY-SA 3.0, Author: Stefan Kühn](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tissot_mercator.png)*

Comment: Just found this old question when working on a similar question and thought I should answer it too for other people having the same problem.