# Why does reprojection with gdalwarp change pixel size?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

Is it okay that reprojection from UTM (EPSG:32612) to Web Mercator (EPSG:3857) with gdalwarp changes pixel size? Why does this happen? Does that mean that unit is not meters? If so, than how to convert pixel size from UTM units to Web Mercator units?

Command:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs" LC08_L1TP_047011_20170518_20170519_01_RT_B4.TIF output.tif
```

Input image is Landsat 8 from AWS:
http://landsat-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/c1/L8/047/011/LC08_L1TP_047011_20170518_20170519_01_RT/LC08_L1TP_047011_20170518_20170519_01_RT_B4.TIF

Original image info:

```
$ gdalinfo LC08_L1TP_047011_20170518_20170519_01_RT_B4.TIF
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /home/user/Desktop/Landsat_sample/LC08_L1TP_047011_20170518_20170519_01_RT_B4.TIF
Size is 8451, 8491
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 12N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-111],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32612"]]
Origin = (488985.000000000000000,7851615.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (30.000000000000000,-30.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  488985.000, 7851615.000) (111d17'58.67"W, 70d46' 6.92"N)
Lower Left  (  488985.000, 7596885.000) (111d16' 8.84"W, 68d29' 3.48"N)
Upper Right (  742515.000, 7851615.000) (104d25'49.46"W, 70d39' 3.78"N)
Lower Right (  742515.000, 7596885.000) (105d 5'39.63"W, 68d22'48.67"N)
Center      (  615750.000, 7724250.000) (108d 1'24.05"W, 69d36' 5.29"N)
Band 1 Block=512x512 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Reprojected image info:

```
$ gdalinfo output.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: out.tif
       out.tif.aux.xml
Size is 8902, 8880
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unnamed ellipse",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["unnamed",6378137,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (-12389818.176861140877008,11323689.164804801344872)
Pixel Size = (85.895238477817642,-85.895238477817642)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-12389818.177,11323689.165) (111d17'58.67"W, 70d46' 7.79"N)
Lower Left  (-12389818.177,10560939.447) (111d17'58.67"W, 68d22'48.98"N)
Upper Right (-11625178.764,11323689.165) (104d25'50.73"W, 70d46' 7.79"N)
Lower Right (-11625178.764,10560939.447) (104d25'50.73"W, 68d22'48.98"N)
Center      (-12007498.470,10942314.306) (107d51'54.70"W, 69d36'28.82"N)
Band 1 Block=8902x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=0.000 Max=52607.000 
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=52607.000, Mean=17537.063, StdDev=16780.853
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=52607
    STATISTICS_MEAN=17537.062597405
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=16780.852772678
```

Comment: Why don't you use  `-t_srs EPSG:3857`. What is the output of gdalinfo if you do that?

Comment: `$ gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 LC08_L1TP_047011_20170518_20170519_01_RT_B4.TIF out3857.tifCreating output file that is 8902P x 8880L.
Processing input file LC08_L1TP_047011_20170518_20170519_01_RT_B4.TIF.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.`

Comment: `$ gdalinfo out3857.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: out3857.tif
Size is 8902, 8880
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],`

Comment: `PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (-12389818.176861140877008,11323689.164804801344872)
Pixel Size = (85.895238477817642,-85.895238477817642)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point`

Comment: `Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-12389818.177,11323689.165) (111d17'58.67"W, 70d46' 7.79"N)
Lower Left  (-12389818.177,10560939.447) (111d17'58.67"W, 68d22'48.98"N)
Upper Right (-11625178.764,11323689.165) (104d25'50.73"W, 70d46' 7.79"N)
Lower Right (-11625178.764,10560939.447) (104d25'50.73"W, 68d22'48.98"N)
Center      (-12007498.470,10942314.306) (107d51'54.70"W, 69d36'28.82"N)
Band 1 Block=8902x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray`

Comment: @RoVo pixel size is changed either way

Comment: @dr_times Please edit the question, rather than losing important information in comments.

Comment: The area has to change. Its about projected area, and different projections make different tradeoffs about what they preserve - area, angle, distance or some compromise.

Comment: This is completely solved by using **-tr** gdalwarp parameter.

Comment: `gdalwarp` is doing the right thing: keeping the total resolution. Forcing pixelsize with `-tr` is the wrong way to go for most use-cases.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**gdalwarp** is doing the right thing: preserving total resolution of your image by changing the pixel-size.

[WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator](http://epsg.io/3857) projection is heavily distorted when moving away from the equator. Thus, it could be discussed if the units should be called "*Pseudo-meters*". One meter in reality is approximately `1/cos(lat)` *pseudo-meters*.

You can calculate the approximate pixel size for your raster image:

```
30m / cos(69.53°) = 85.78 pseudo-meters
```

Compare this with your `gdalinfo` output.

[image: Tissot Indicatrix]

*[CC BY-SA 3.0, Author: Stefan Kühn](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tissot_mercator.png)*

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, in Web Mercator the measurement units are not really meters.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29672432/4828720

Look at your resulting images, they are probably vastly different in looks.

Comment: They are in metres. Its projected, and an approximation, but its metres.

Comment: thank you! the document provided on stack overflow is very informative