# PostGIS Geometric V Geography measurements when using ST_Length

Tags: postgis, geometry, measurements

I was measuring geometry using some PostGIS functions and noticed that I was getting different results from the two methods I used.

```
sum(st_length(st_transform(geom, 3857))) # Gave 3674

sum(st_length(geom::geography)) # Gave 1671
```

Why am I seeing different results?  I was expecting a slight deviation but this seems to be quite significant.

Is there something wrong with how am I using these queries?

Comment: (Web) Mercator is very bad for distance/area calculations. What is the length when you use the regional UTM zone? It should be similar to 1671.

Comment: Indeed, using the UTM zone does give the same result as st_length(geom::geography)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EPSG:3857` is also known as Web Mercator.
Usual Mercator projections preserve angles but creates important distortions of size. Web Mercator has slight distortion of angles.

> Web Mercator shares some of the same properties of the standard
>   Mercator projection: north is up everywhere, meridians are equally
>   spaced vertical lines, but areas near the poles are greatly
>   exaggerated.
>
> Unlike the ellipsoidal Mercator and spherical Mercator, the Web
>   Mercator is not quite conformal due to its use of ellipsoidal datum
>   geographical coordinates against a spherical projection. Rhumb lines
>   are not straight lines. The benefit is that the spherical form is much
>   simpler to calculate, saving many computing cycles

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator)

[Tissot's indicatrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissot%27s_indicatrix) show how equal area circles look like when they are projected.

Here is the result for Web Mercator:
[image: Web Mercator]

[Source](http://cartonerd.blogspot.be/2014/08/web-mercator-and-comparisons.html)

- [A more in-depth explanation from ESRI](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/03/05/measuring-distances-and-areas-when-your-map-uses-the-mercator-projection/)
- And [why Web Mercator is not conformal](http://hydrometronics.com/downloads/Web%20Mercator%20-%20Non-Conformal,%20Non-Mercator%20(notes).pdf) (thanks user30184)

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245151/why-does-reprojection-with-gdalwarp-change-pixel-size/245156#245156

Comment: EPSG:3857 does not preserve angles. Mercator does, web Mercator doesn't. See http://hydrometronics.com/downloads/Web%20Mercator%20-%20Non-Conformal,%20Non-Mercator%20(notes).pdf

Comment: @user30184 yes you are right I will correct the answer

Comment: Thanks.  My coordinate system knowledge has just got a lot better.