# PostGIS ST_Distance in meters discrepancy

Tags: postgis, gdal

Could someone please explain why there is such a significant difference between the results of this query:

```
SELECT 
    ST_Distance(ST_Transform(previous_geom,3857), ST_Transform(current_geom,3857)) AS distance_transform_exp,
    ST_Distance(previous_geom::geography, current_geom::geography) AS distance_geometry_exp
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-111.9096893, 40.7411742),4326) AS previous_geom,
        ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-111.9092079, 40.74135181),4326) AS current_geom
) points_table
```

Results:

```
 distance_transform_exp | distance_geometry_exp
+-----------------------+-----------------------
       59.6050787601899 |           45.19182216
(1 row)
```

I understand there would be a difference between geometric (Cartesian) calculation results and geodetic (spheroid) alas for the example points which are relatively close, the discrepancy would be expected to be negligible.

Comment: try this function on the geographies https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the question is different, the answer is the same as [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245151/why-does-reprojection-with-gdalwarp-change-pixel-size/245156#245156).

---

`ST_Distance(previous_geom::geography, current_geom::geography)` is the correct result.

WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator (EPSG:3857) projection is heavily distorted when moving away from the equator. Thus, it could be discussed if the units should be called "*Pseudo-meters*". One meter in reality is approximately 1/cos(lat) pseudo-meters.

```
45.19 m / cos(40.7°) = 59.6 pseudo-meters
```

[image]

*[CC BY-SA 3.0, Author: Stefan Kühn](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tissot_mercator.png)*

Comment: so distances should never be measured in 3857?

Comment: Exactly. Better to use postgis' geography type or the local standard CRS, e.g. the UTM zones.

Comment: so if google maps is in 3857 how do they give back accurate distances?

Comment: The pictures are 3857 but not the measurements probably ...

Comment: right, and there geocoder returns 4326 lat longs

Comment: @RoVo: Thank you for your answer. Since EPSG:3857 has meters as its unit of measurement why would it not be a reliable medium for distances calculations? I imagine the stretching of a spheroid onto a planar surface introduces errors, would an infinitesimally small area on a sphere not be flat enough to approximate a 2D plane?

Comment: because its not meters. only pseudo-meters

Comment: It is flat but it is made flat by stretching the world balloon very heavily near the poles. Meter was meter only before the stretch.

Comment: The only "latitude of true scale" in a mercator projection is at the equator. So you can do direct planar calculations as long as your working area is (a) small and (b) at the equator. If you're willing to scale your results by `1/cos(phi)` you can do direct planar calculations as long as (a) your area of interest is small (b) you remember to scale your result.